# Bubble Javascript event manually

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, event-bubbling

Imagine I have this code:

```
var event = new Event('build');
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Now somewhere in the code I have something like that:

```
elem.addEventListener('build', function (e) { });
```

Now what I want, is to take event `e` and dispatch it again, I mean bubble it up manually, so it will continue propagation without property `{bubbles: true}`. Something like that:

```
elem.addEventListener('build', function (e) { elem.dispatchEvent(e) } );
```

But I don't think this will work.

Comment: `elem.parentNode.dispatch` - ?

Comment: @georg that would also require that elem.parentNode has itself an event listener so it can continue to bubble up. @OP, why don't you want to use `bubble: true`?